# How to load (n>2)-level nested data from denormalized dataset with Firebase/AngularFire?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Given a denormalized data structure like:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "-JMMXslDJkPYmgcwXUzP" : {
      "items" : [ "-JMMXYaWlg_ftL2sKsdp", ... ],
      "name" : "user0"
    },
    ...
  },
  "items" : {
    "-JMMXYac7EMZcr4LIL5u" : {
      "properties" : [ "-JMMWdpWig-L8oIqbeI1", ... ],
      "name" : "item0"
    },
    ...
  },
  "properties" : {
    "-JMMWdpe3WEyjnUM12o2" : {"name": "property0"},
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm currently loading nested children like so:

```
<ul ng-init="users = $ref('users')">
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">
        <h1>{{ user.name }}</h1>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item_id in user.items" ng-init="item = $ref('items/'+item_id)">
                <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="property_id in item.properties" ng-init="property = $ref('properties/'+property_id)">
                        <h3>{{ property.name}}</h3>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the plunker showing how unbearably slow loading becomes with only 3-levels-deep-nested data: http://plnkr.co/edit/yrRx2FYJEc5BM1MaSQDe?p=preview

**How can I speed up the loading/rendering of this data?**

- Note that the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21737084/888928) (creating one reference for each collection instead of each collection item) will not work for me, since any/all of my nested collections will be too big.

Comment: Do you need persistent two-way binding on all pieces of data you're outputting? If not, have you looked at bindonce? https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

Comment: I do, unfortunately--at least for most of the collections. I'll see what I can do to switch what I can over to bindonce, but I suspect it won't be enough.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is the compiler. Each time any of those records changes, all of those ng-repeat ops are being re-run, and the data is being downloaded again and again. Instead, use a cache of items.

Since I've written [an example of a user cache previously](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/LCa6j/), I'll just borrow from that and switch out the variables to match your examples. You'll need to adapt it to work with multiple items belonging to each user; forgive me for that laziness:

The view:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users" ng-init="item = items.$load(user.item_id)">
    {{user.name}}: {{item.name}}
</li>
```

And the controller:

```
// CONTROLLER

app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $firebase, itemCache) {
    $scope.users = $firebase(fb.child('users'));
    $scope.items = itemCache(fb.child('items'));
    $scope.$on('$destroy', $scope.items.$dispose);
});

app.factory('itemCache', function ($firebase) {
    return function (ref) {
        var cachedItems = {};
        cachedItems.$load = function (id) {
            if( !cachedItems.hasOwnProperty(id) ) {
                cachedItems[id] = $firebase(ref.child(id));
            }
            return cachedItems[id];
        };
        cachedItems.$dispose = function () {
            angular.forEach(cachedItems, function (item) {
                item.$off();
            });
        };
        return cachedItems;
    }
});
```

Comment: Caching doesn't appear to have any significant effect on the performance of the app. Is there a way to prevent firebase from blocking the app while it downloads its data?

Comment: Firebase ops are async, not blocking.

Comment: I understand, but the amount of data being streamed seems to lock up the browser while it is streaming, thereby appearing 'blocked'.